# ocultar el puerto en mi URL

Tags: php, apache, puertos

Bueno les escribo porque tengo un problema que no logro solucionar ya buen tiempo sucede que tengo una pagina con una www.mipagina.com.pe:8080 pero sucede que no deseo que salga el puerto 8080(o cualquier puerto) y solo salga www.mipagina.com.pe .Ahora estado haciendo configuraciones en el apache pero sigo teniendo error, estado aplicando virtualhost pero igual tengo resultado no positivos espero me puedan ayudar.Saludos
De donde saque la informacion fue de esta pagina http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/host/ espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes,

No puedes ocultar el puerto de la URL si el utilizado no es el por defecto. No es cuestión de tu URL concreta (lo digo por que no pierdas el tiempo con urls amigables), si no de que tienes que **indicar al navegador** que debe ir al puerto 8080 en vez de al puerto 80. Al no utilizar el puerto por defecto, es obligatorio notificar el puerto a utilizar. Es como funciona una conexión http.

Si lo que tienes es un problema con Apache en sí, deberías compartir la configuración que tienes para poder entender por que no puedes levantar apache en el puerto por defecto (probablemente esté en uso o bien mal configurado).

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

trata esto,

se llama url amigables.

integra un .htaccess en tu raíz de archivos ahí configura el .htacces

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

estas lineas de código son para la configuración que escribirás en dicho archivo 
después de la configuración intenta hacer esto

```
RewriteRule ^loquequieras/$ 8080
```

este fragmento de código espera reescribir las url que tu quieras, espero que te funcione

Answer (score 0):

Tan sólo cambiar el virtual host, no es suficiente. Necesitas que Apache "escuche" en el puerto 80 (Listen 80 | Port 80) para lo cual necesitarás permiso en el sistema operativo. La configuración también cambia si estás usando Windows o Linux. Los puertos menores a 1024 necesitan ser iniciados con algún tipo de permiso elevado (root en Linux o administrator en Windows). Espero que esto te ayude a entender mejor la solución.